# tkinter filedialog without hidden folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

as in title:

Any idea how to use that box without displaying hidden folders in it?
Also would be nice to know if I could display folders with certain name pattern etc.

Current code (as short as make sense to work):

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog

def opendir():
    mp3dir = tk.filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/home/", title="Choose folder")
    print (mp3dir)

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("120x45")

button1 = tk.Button(win,text="Open folder", command=opendir)
button1.pack(padx=5,pady=5)


win.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe so. Source for filedialog.py doesn't have any options for this. The hidden file visibility (certainly on windows) is set by the OS. You can filter files but not folders.